# Is there a way to set the default format to use when formatting numbers in Flex 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

For instance, my application is formatting negative numbers with parenthesis by default. I would like for it to use the negative sign instead but across my entire application and not on a per number formatter basis.

Is there somewhere I can globally set some defaults so I don't have to depend on each NumberFormatter() instance in the entire application?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, there's nothing like what you describe.  Off the top of my head, could you 1) use an application wide `static const` for the desired number format and reference that everywhere you create a number formatter? or 2) use a `NumberFormatterFactory` that sets the desired format before returning the `NumberFormatter` object to the calling code?

Comment: That works but only in instances where the NumberFormatter is actually called to format a new number. I was looking for something that instead handled all formatting of numbers regardless of whether or not I was specifically handling it in a NumberFormatter. Too good to be true I suppose.

Comment: It's probably worth editing your question to focus more on that broad applicability.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all the negative numbers formatted by parenthesis instead of minus sign, is becuase of your OS' regional number format settings.
By defult Flash picks up formatting information from your OS.
So if you change your OS' regional number format settings to show a minus sign for negative numbers, then you will see all numbers formatted with that.

If you want to implement L10N in your project, then you will have to use labelFunction / formatString properties of the columns / text fields and format the numbers to formats selected by user in your project's L10N settings. Flex's Globalization package will be handy for this. Checkout [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_globalization_package.html).